# Using include function that doesn't take js and css of the page where it is included

Tags: javascript, php, css

Hypothetical example: I have two pages
index.php
header.php

Both pages use different CSS and JS for the look and response.

When I include header.php in the index.php it takes over CSS of the index.php and messes it all up, alone header.php works fine

```
  <?php  include 'header.php'; ?>
```

Is there a way to still use the header.php and don't use the CSS of the index.php

Comment: Would it be better to make the CSS so that it works with both sets of files.  This may mean renaming some classes etc. but will mean you have a more consistent way of doing things.

Comment: @NigelRen yes, but in this case renaming classes doesn't seem to be a viable option to be. looking for a solution to this